# CSS's overflow-x and overflow-y are not widely supported?

Tags: css

Strange, I thought `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` are both widely supported, but then I just saw that it is only supported for CSS3
( http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/overflow ), so IE 7 doesn't support it?

Is there a way to simulate an `overflow-y: auto` then?  (while keeping `overflow-x: hidden`)?

Answer (score 3):

The link you posted has the answer:

"The CSS3 overflow-x and overflow-y properties are partially supported in Internet Explorer for windows versions 5 and 6 and fully supported in Internet Explorer versions 7 & 8. Safari 3+, Chrome 2+, Firefox 2+ and Opera 9.5+ all support these properties."

Comment: so ditch ie6 and live happily ever after!